# Compare 2 lists of objects, return percentage match c#

Tags: c#, list, compare, percentage, listobject

I am looking for compare two list of objects; to know the langage of a corpus. The list of reference is build by a txt. Same for the corpus.

list Ref  / list Corpus

```
    public Canagram(string anagram, int frequency,int percentage)
    {
        anagram = Anagram;         // exemple "a"
        frequency = Frequency;     // how many "a" in the txt 
        percentage = Percentage;   // what's the percentage compared to the other anagram
    }
```

The goal is to match each anagram on each list with the percentage and return the global percentage match between this two lists.

```
    public static int percentage(List<Canagram> reference, List<Canagram> corpus)
    {

        //don"t know how to compare this two list properly and return % match

        return (int) percentage of match;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you comparing? are you comparing `anagram` or `anagram` * `frequency`, or...?

Comment: I would like to compare all anagrams of the corpus (if it's in the refer list or not) and compare the percentage of this anagram, to know later wich langage was use in this corpus. 

For exemple i got list anagram from french.txt / spanish.txt / english.txt -> I would like to know the langage of text.txt by comparing his list of anagram with other list of anagram

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but maybe try something like:

```
int cnt = reference.Count;
int matches = 0;
foreach (var phrase in reference)
{
if (corpus.Contains(phrase))
    matches++
}
double percent = (double)matches / (double)cnt;
```

You might need to modify the type so that it can work with the standard Contains, or you will have to write a custom MyContains so that you could determine.

I haven't compiled the above, so please excuse the typos, but I believe you should get the jist.